# how to make zip archive in ansible faster?

Tags: ansible, zip, archive

I'm trying to compress a folder to a .zip file via Ansible using the archive module. The docs describe an attributes parameters, have you used it?
And do you know how to speed up the archiving?

P.S.: I know that making a .tar is better, but in my situation only a .zip file can be used.

```
- name: zip backup folder linux
  archive:
    path: "{{ path_from }}/*"
    dest: "{{ path_to }}/backup_{{backup_name}}.zip"
    format: zip
```

Answer (score 0):

change archive to command module: so speed up compressing with terminal

Comment: Using shell commands while there are official modules available isn't recommended.

Comment: agree, but if module doesn't has these attributes - shell is better

Comment: There isn't any statement in OP's question that he can't use the archive the module.

Answer (score 0):

[The archive module has the ability to compresses a file/folder](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/archive_module.html), using the Linux system packages:

- tarfile
- zipfile
- gzip
- bzip2

In short, Ansible adds a layer on top of those system packages to execute the compressing task.
Speeding things up are out of Ansible's control, as it relies on those tools.

The time it takes to compress files/folders greatly relies on the following items:

- CPU
- RAM
- Disk (SSD or HDD)
- Amount of files to compress
- Kind of file
- Version of tools and OS

If you find a way to actually speed things up with another system command, either use shell for a quick and dirty method, or add your method to the Ansible Core, since Ansible is open source.

You might want to google for something like "benchmark zip compression" and look whatever fits your situation best.